# How do i normalize image in android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am working on camera based application.
I want to normalize image that is captured by device's camera.
Is it possible to normalize image in android? any idea how can i do that?

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by normalize ? Do you want to crop the image ?

Comment: @Grishu : thanks for reply, i want normalize like this in Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324840/grayscale-normalized-histogram-without-using-hist-matlab.

Comment: I think you want to resize your image right ?

Comment: Assuming you already have your image as a Bitmap (which you should from the camera iirc) you should be able to use the Bitmap.getPixel(x, y) and Bitmap.setPixel(x, y, colour) methods described on the Bitmap docs page on the Android developer site [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and iterate over each pixel in your image to set it to whatever value you want (the code will not be as concise as the MatLab code you linked but you should be able to get the same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Catalano Framework](https://code.google.com/archive/p/catalano-framework/). Here contains the [article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/656059/catalano-framework) that you can learn how to use.

I implemented Image Normalization using this approach.

```
FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap("image.jpg");
fb.toGrayscale();

ImageNormalization in = new ImageNormalization();
in.applyInPlace(fb);
```